# angular $resource delete - passing id parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to implement an angular service using $resource. I could implement the query method which returns results. Now I'm blocked with delete service.

My service code is:

```
var Customer = $resource(Globals.URL_WS + 'admin/customers/:customerId', {customerId:'@id'}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                return angular.fromJson(data).data;
            }
        }
    });
```

Then in the controller I want to use a remove method :

```
Customer.remove({customerId: custId}, function() {
            ...
        }
```

The custId has a value, but my url, when I'm calling the remove method, doesn't have id param so I recieve 405 error. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: 405 is method not allowed. Check if your server allows the DELETE verb.

Comment: yes, it allows. the 405 error is because my code tries to delete without passing id param, which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

In your demo code the request could make something like: '/admin/customers/42'. where '42' is the customer ID. This is not a URL parameter, it IS part of the url and should be handled by the server respectively.

If you really want a URL Parameter like /customers?id=42 change your service to this:

```
return $resource('/admin/customers', {customerId:'@id'}, {..
```

(Remove the '/:customerId' from the URL.